# How can I remove the branding from the free getbutton.io?

Tags: wordpress, widget

I received this, I want to remove the branding. Is there any why to do so? please note that I'm not a developer myself and use elementor builder. Thanks in advance

```html
<!-- GetButton.io widget -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        var options = {
            whatsapp: "123456789", // WhatsApp number
            call_to_action: "Call US", // Call to action
            position: "right", // Position may be 'right' or 'left'
        };
        var proto = document.location.protocol, host = "getbutton.io", url = proto + "//static." + host;
        var s = document.createElement('script'); s.type = 'text/javascript'; s.async = true; s.src = url + '/widget-send-button/js/init.js';
        s.onload = function () { WhWidgetSendButton.init(host, proto, options); };
        var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
    })();
</script>
<!-- /GetButton.io widget -->
```

Answer (score 0):

This is only available in the Pro version according to the plugin page.

> Get more chats and sales with PRO features:
>
> ```
> Enable the Greeting Message.
> **Remove the ‘GetButton’ link.**
> Add up to ten buttons to the widget.
> Choose any custom color for the button.
> ```

// https://wordpress.org/plugins/whatshelp-chat-button/

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBPRU.png)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBPRU.png

```css
Insert <head> <head> code and removed adv.

<style>
.dmopMx{
visibility: hidden;
}
</style>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).